# GPS Status Listener

Tags: java, android, gps, listener

I'm just trying to listen to GPS status changes. I have the following:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    lm.addGpsStatusListener(new android.location.GpsStatus.Listener() {

        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            switch (event) {
                case GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                    if((alertDialog != null) && (alertDialog.isShowing())){
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    contador=0;
                    darHandle();
                    break;
                case GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                    if(mProgressDialog!=null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    contador=0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

It works nicely in my Moto G 1st, but it is deprecated and doesn't work in some devices.

I'm trying to figure out how to use `onProviderEnabled()`/`onProviderDisabled()` in that scenario. I have tried many code examples but didn't get it working.

I'm right now trying this one:

```
LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 12000, 0, locationListenerGps);
```

But in the last line it says:

Cannot resolve method `requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, int, int, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)`

Answer (score 0):

this just happened to me.

I think your problem has to be with the class of the listener imported.

There are two kinds:

that one you used: [com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

and: [android.location.LocationListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener)

Those methods you are using belong to the second one. 
Use that one and you should go fine.

In Android usually happens this things, so be alert, there are many classes for different APIs, and some of them repeat names and you have to try combinations.